# In practical, how to find the friction of rubber vs plastic?

Tags: friction

I did an experiment. The experiment was to use a gripper which had rubber fingers to grip a plastic rod which attached to a mass. After that I had a linear motor to move the gripper.

What I wanted to see was that the rod with a mass was moved by the gripper which was driven by linear motor.

Technically, the length of the rod which is gripped by the rubber fingers does not related to the area that gripped by the rubber finger because F=uN, friction force by the rubber gripper has no relation with the area.

However,it does make some different. It has higher chance to move the heavier mass.

Does there are more than just F=uN that I need to concern?

Comment: Are you asking whether the surface area of contact between the rubber fingers and the object matters in how much friction force can be applied?

Comment: Related: [Why is the equation for friction so simple?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154443/why-is-the-equation-for-friction-so-simple)