# How to approximate friction coefficients between different materials?

Tags: friction, approximations

I want to add friction forces to my computer game. I know there are tables for friction, however I don't think that encoding big table of coefficients (of size $n^2$) is a good idea.

I thought, that there may exist some characteristic $\lambda$ for each material, so that friction between materials $a$ and $b$ is approximated by $\mu_{a,b}=f(\lambda_a, \lambda_b)$ for some function $f$.

Do such characteristic and function $f$ exist? Note that I need this for computer game and I don't need big accuracy, only correct behavior.

Comment: Somnium, I'm not aware that such a function exists.  However, I'll attempt to set something up and see if I can develop such a function.

Comment: Have you tried to develop such a relation yourself mathematically? If it is only a game and you don't need accuracy, it doesn't really matter what coefficients you use, does it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heuristic equation for Friction force between materials](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104723).