# Why doesn't friction depend upon area of contact?

Tags: friction

Even though the pressure increases when the area of contact decreases why doesn't friction increase with decrease in area?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! I've reverted an edit where you asked a separate interesting question; I thought the second one was different enough to stand on its own.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependence of Friction on Area](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16213/)

Answer (score -1):

Friction is directly proportional to the normal force acting on the body, i.e.;

$$f \propto N$$
where $f =$ *friction force* and $N =$ *Normal force*

$$\boxed {f = \mu N}$$

where $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction and depends upon the surface.

[image]

We can also say that the normal force does not depend upon the area of contact and hence the friction.

Pressure, on the other hand is:

$$\boxed{P = \frac{F}{A}}$$

where $F$ is the force acting and $A$ is the Area of contact. Thus pressure depends upon the area of contact.